# Marvel Digital Comics Giveaway

Tags: discussion, contest

I'm giving away a few codes for Marvel Digital Comics bundles.  The bundles contain these issues:

- Superior Iron Man #1
- Black Widow #1
- Captain America #1
- Thor God of Thunder #1
- Hawkeye #1
- Hulk #1
- Avengers Origins: Scarlet Witch & Quicksilver #1

I've got 4 bundle codes, each contains all of these comics.  The giveaway is pretty simple, just post an answer here before the end of May 16 (UTC) to enter.  Afterwards, I'll roll a random number generator to pick the winners.

Fine print:  You must have a Sci-fi & Fantasy Stack Exchange account older than this post.  Redeem the codes at http://marvel.com/redeem.  Requires a Marvel.com account (you can link your Marvel.com account to Comixology so these comics will show up in your Comixology account).  The download codes expire on 7/31/15 at 11:59:59 PM ET.

### Winners

- Eric McCormick
- Bobson
- Mooz
- PrisonMonkeys

### Thanks

Thanks to Jack B Nimble and Michael Edenfield for contributing codes to the prize pool!

Comment: / coughs. Looks like a good deal...

Comment: “Superior Iron Man”? Did Doctor Octopus take over Tony Stark now??

Answer (score 1):

I've been tempted to get into digital Marvel comics for a while, and I've never read any comics before (only watched the MCU flicks), so that bundle sounds useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this sort if thing before...and is be happy to do so again.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great offer. I like those MCU movies pretty much but have never ever read a single comic in my life (apart from *Watchmen*). So this sounds like a great opportunity to get a little more background in the matter.

Answer (score 0):

I always wanted to read all Marvel Comics but didn't know  where to start so I guess it would be cool to start my journey.

Answer (score 0):

Ooh, I haven't seen any recent issues (most of my collection is still silver age....)
Would love to get a head start on catching up :-)

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a perfect way to expand my comics collection, although I'm going to have a hard time showing these off in my book case...

Comment: Congratulations, you've won!  Shoot me an email at **REMOVED**.

Answer (score 0):

I have not really read many comics in the past, but have grown very fond of the genres. I would ***love*** to receive this pack!

Comment: Congratulations, you've won!  Shoot me an email at **REMOVED**.

Comment: No way? SICK!! Thanks dude. I'd like to take this opportunity to thank my wife, my mother, my colleagues who also applied for this prize and most of all my fans; without whom I could never have done this!

Answer (score 0):

Having never read a comic book in my life, I'd be super interested in winning this. But until then, you can hold this:

*hands over a NERD card*

Answer (score 0):

I've always been turned off of comics due to all the continuity issues, but that is something the MCU seems to be keeping tight control over.  I'd love to give the format another try.

Comment: Congratulations, you've won!  Shoot me an email at **REMOVED**.

Comment: @Keen - Oh cool.  Email sent.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

That's fantastic. I'm very eager to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Love to get my hands into digital comics.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in.  MCU is the first thing that's made me want to read a comic since Appleseed.  Thanks for the offer!

Answer (score 0):

Alright!
Never read a digital comic - would be eager to see how it works out.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a pretty cool thing.

Answer (score 0):

Hey thanks for this great offering to the community!  Top stuff (although I've not read any online comics before but I'm sure they're great!)

Answer (score 0):

I have been considering trying to get my son to read comics.  Though improving, his reading level is below where it should be.  I figure any kind of reading is better than no reading, and he loves the Marvel movies.  This would certainly be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Awesome sauce. I'm ready, roll the dice!

Comment: Congratulations, you've won!  Shoot me an email at **REMOVED**.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't mind some free comics :)

Answer (score 0):

Cool giveaway.  Would be fun to read these.